# Определить количество положительных чисел

Tags: c#

Написать программу, в которой пользователь вводит несколько чисел, программа выводит количество положительных чисел.

```
int x, y = 0, z, b;
Console.WriteLine("Введите колличество цифр: ");
x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите число 1: ");
x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите число 2: ");
x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите число 3: ");
x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
{
    if (x >= 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Положительных чисел: " + x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Вам нужна отдельная переменная, чтобы считать количество положительных чисел.

Answer (score 1):

Протестируйте и разберите это решение.

```cs
Console.Write("Введите колличество чисел: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Введите число {i + 1}: ");
    int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (x > 0)
        count++;
}
Console.WriteLine($"Положительных чисел: {count}");
```

Познакокомьтесь с [отладкой](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019), пошаговое выполнение кода сильно помогает понять, что происходит, когда программа выполняется.